# Passing variable arguments to a java function from javascript using GraalVM

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, corda, graalvm

I am trying to call a function available in Corda RPC called  [`startTrackedFlowDynamic`](https://docs.corda.net/api/kotlin/corda/net.corda.core.messaging/-corda-r-p-c-ops/start-tracked-flow-dynamic.html) which accepts 2 arguments: 
`startTrackedFlowDynamic(logicType: Class<out FlowLogic<T>>, vararg args: Any?)` which is packaged in a JAR

The call to this function is made from a **Javascript context** (using GraalVM to achieve that), I want to call this function and pass the arguments to it obtained from a request  object (say, coming from a REST API)

Example:
if the request contains an array `[::InitiatorA, iouValue]`,
I would want to call startTrackedFlowDynamic like:
`startTrackedFlowDynamic(::InitiatorA, iouValue)`

if the request contains an array `[::InitiatorB, abc, xyz]`
I would want to call startTrackedFlowDynamic like:
`startTrackedFlowDynamic(::InitiatorB, abc, xyz)`

if the request contains an array `[::InitiatorC]`
I would want to call startTrackedFlowDynamic like:
`startTrackedFlowDynamic(::InitiatorC)`

TLDR: I would like to make it as a generic API instead of re-writing for every different Flow call.
I want to be able to pass dynamic number of arguments coming from the request object to this function instead of hard coding a fixed number of arguments and having to update it when the number of argument changes

An **example** of the behaviour I want to replicate:

```js
var func = function () {
    console.log(arguments.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        console.log(arguments[i]);
    }
};

func.apply(null, ['::InitiatorA', 'abc', 'xyz'])
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'd suggest using in example `console.log` instead of `alert` - it's less annoying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to work with the following JavaScript syntax

```
var argsArray = ['::InitiatorA', 'abc', 'xyz']
startTrackedFlowDynamic(...argsArray)
```